# Why does Celery use polling with the Redis broker?

Tags: python, redis, celery

According to [its documentation on the `interval` option](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get) Celery *polls* for results when using the Redis backend, by default using a 0.5s interval.

A naive developer could think that any queueing system using Redis would at least try to exploit its LIST or PUBSUB mechanisms. Why does Celery not do this and instead rely on polling?

As an example, the following takes exactly **0.5 seconds** on the `r.get()` call when run through a Celery worker (which is the default polling interval):

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
              backend="redis://localhost:6379/0")

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = add.delay(5, 4)
    result = r.get()
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polling is the default implementation for any new result store because it works without backend-specific code. Using Redis PUB/SUB is on the wish list; the code simply hasn't been written yet: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/799